# What are the specifics of WordPress development I need to know?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, theme-development

I have worked with PHP for 8 years and with Laravel for 5 years. And I did realize a lot of complex websites completely by myself. But I still don't understand the concept of WordPress specific development.

I have tried everything (reading documentation , watching videos , reading book) but I couldn't learn it.

I know some people who don't know that much on PHP and programming, but they are working on WordPress and everything is ok for them.

Is it possible that I have missed some main point or something?

Please can you provide me your story on how you started and what did you do?

Comment: if you know laravel and php very will then way you need to learn wordpress ? ?

Comment: thank you for your response ,  not all the time Laravel  and pure php is an easy  solution . working on website from scratch is harder than working on it from the last some step :) , like magazine or news website it's very easy to do it in WordPress and it may take 2 or three days and maybe less

Comment: You came to the right place. When I came here I only had basic knowledge of WordPress. And PHP, just to be honest. Over time I learned a lot and was able to work in that field for quite some time, now I'm just doing it for fun. Pretty much everything you need to know you can find here: https://developer.wordpress.org/  With your PHP skills you should have a steep learning curve. If you need more ans specific help, you can ask questions here.

Comment: I don't have much in the way of comments here except if you're an accomplished PHP developer, you'll be fine. If you're distributing your code into plugins, for example, you'll be fine if you (a) assume all other developer code is terrible and you check your data to ensure it is what you think it is before you use it if you ever get it from, or pass it through, filters; (b) if you're distributing your code, ensure your code is php 5.2 compatible and if not, ensure your plugin does a check for the compatible PHP version before allowing itself to be fully loaded.

Comment: @Nicolai  how much it take with you to be a really WordPress developer ? and why you made the question on hold after you edit it :p

Comment: It was just a suggestion. Besides you can specify your problem and the question will be on topic.

Comment: @amir if you're looking for an application framework, or a set of classes and interfaces you must implement, then you won't find any as WP doesn't provide any. Plugins are just PHP files with a comment at the top, themes are a folder of template files and a `functions.php` that's the same as  a plugin, and an action/filter system. beyond that you have to provide the structure yourself. That might be by bringing in Laravel stuff, rolling your own, procedural, even Symfony components

Comment: @amir also remember, this is a Q/A site not a discussion forum, you need to be able to mark an answer as **the** canonical answer, the answer that absolutely answers the question. So open ended questions or super broad ones don't fit the format and aren't very useful.